# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'w3c' in Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to make an action from keyboard that I would like to make an action press `TAB` key from keyboard but it through for me this error message

> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'w3c'

This is my code for that

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from Pages.loginPage import LoginPage

class createDevice(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/admin/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        driver = cls.driver
        driver.get("https://admin-helper-f21c1.web.app/login")
        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_email("admin@gmail.com")
        login.enter_password("123456")
        login.click_login()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_create_device_03(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sidebar"]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//main//div/button[@type='button']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys(" ")
        action = ActionChains(webdriver)
        action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()=' Device name is required. ']").is_displayed()
        print("'Device name is required.' displayed")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Could anyone explain to me what does that mean and how can I fix this problem? I already search for it but I did not found the answer to work for me. Please help me! thank you so much

Comment: can you post your whole traceback?

Answer (score 0):

[`ActionChains()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) accepts the instance of a [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) as an argument.

In this usecase, the *WebDriver* instance is **`self.driver`** where as you have passed `webdriver`